# Why does spring empty my database table when I start the server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a database table `roles` with 96 predefined data rows, but when I start the server (that is running on Tomcat 8.5.28) it empties that table. I was wondering why it would do that?

**RoleController**

```
@RestController
public class RoleController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RoleController.class);

    final RoleServiceImpl roleService;

    @Autowired
    public RoleController(RoleServiceImpl roleService) {
        this.roleService = roleService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Iterable<Role> getAllRolesByName() {
        return roleService.list();
    }
}
```

**Role** (model/ Entity)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    // region: constructors

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // endregion: constructors

    // region: getters & setters

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // endregion: getters & setters

    // region: methods

    // endregion: methods
}
```

**RoleServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class RoleServiceImpl implements RoleService {

    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    public RoleServiceImpl(RoleRepository roleRepository) {
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    }

    public Iterable<Role> list() {
        return roleRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**RoleService**

```
public interface RoleService {
}
```

**RoleRepository**

```
public interface RoleRepository extends CrudRepository<Role, Integer> {
}
```

I could just load in the predefined 96 data rows each time I start the server, but I was wondering if this is normal. (i.e. if this server was live and I had to shut it down for maintenance or something like that, would it empty all the data from the tables? I find that a bit odd. )
--- extra notes ---
I'm using Postgres and Hibernate. And my configuration is 100% Java.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check what is the value substituted for field "**hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto**" in the hibernate properties file.

If hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = **"create" or "create-drop"** that would be causing to delete the data during the server restart.

Answer (score 0):

hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = "create" or "create-drop" forces the db to reset.

Comment: This should be a comment, ma'am... Not an answer. Answers require detail.